# Fetching each word from a text file into text field in java

Tags: java

I'm trying to fetch a set of words stored in a text file into a text field one after the other i.e in my form i have a text field and a button, when i click on the button the word present in the text file must be displayed in the text field and when i click the button again, the second word in the text file must be displayed in the text field and so on. I was able to write a program to fetch a single word but not in a loop. Please guide me with this issue. Thanks in advance.

```
//textview.java  

import java.util.Scanner;  
import java.io.*;  
public class textview   
{  
Scanner scan;  
static String name;   
public void Open()  
{  
try  
{  
scan =new Scanner(new File("F:/MajorProject-NLP/Databases/DataFiles/split.txt")); 
}  
catch(FileNotFoundException e)  
{  
    System.out.println("It wont working");  
}  
}  
public void Read()  
{  
    do  
    {  
       name=scan.next();  

     }  
       while(scan.hasNext());  
       System.out.println(name);  
       scan.close();  
 }  
}  

  // this is my another file where the fetch button is placed.

 import javax.swing.*;
 import java.awt.*;
 import java.io.BufferedWriter;
 import java.io.FileWriter;
 import java.awt.event.ActionEvent;
 import java.awt.event.ActionListener;

 class ReadTextFile extends JFrame
 {
  public static String N;
  private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;
  JButton save,fetch;
  JPanel panel;
  JLabel label1,label2,label3,label4,label5;
  final JTextField text1,text2,text3,text4,text5;

  ReadTextFile(){
  label1 = new JLabel();
  label1.setText("English Word:");
  text1 = new JTextField(20);

  label2 = new JLabel();
  label2.setText("English Synonym:");
  text2 = new JTextField(20);

  label3 = new JLabel();
  label3.setText("Kannada Word:");
  text3 = new JTextField(20);

  label4 = new JLabel();
  label4.setText("Kannada Synonym:");
  text4 = new JTextField(20);

  label5 = new JLabel();
  label5.setText("Parts of Speech:");
  text5 = new JTextField(20);

  save=new JButton("SAVE");
  fetch=new JButton("NEXT");

  panel=new JPanel(new GridLayout(6,2));
  panel.add(label1);
  panel.add(text1);
  panel.add(label2);
  panel.add(text2);
  panel.add(label3);
  panel.add(text3);
  panel.add(label4);
  panel.add(text4);
  panel.add(label5);
  panel.add(text5);
  panel.add(save);
  panel.add(fetch);
  add(panel,BorderLayout.CENTER);
  setTitle("Word Base");

  save.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
  public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent ae){
  String value1=text1.getText();
  String value2=text2.getText();
  String value3=text3.getText();
  String value4=text4.getText();
  String value5=text5.getText();
  try
  {
    FileWriter fstream = new FileWriter("F:/MajorProject-NLP/Databases/DataFiles/pos.txt",true);
        BufferedWriter out = new BufferedWriter(fstream);
    out.write(" ");
    out.write(value1);
        out.write(" ");
    out.write(value2);
    out.write(" ");
    out.write(value3);
    out.write(" ");
    out.write(value4);
    out.write(" ");
    out.write(value5);
    out.write(" ");
    out.write("\n");
    out.close();
  }
  catch(Exception e)
  {
    System.err.println("Error"+e.getMessage());
  }
  text1.setText("");
  text2.setText("");
  text3.setText("");
  text4.setText("");
  text5.setText("");
 }

 });

 fetch.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
     public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent ae){
          if(ae.getSource()==fetch)
          { 
            text1.setText(N);
              }
  });
  }
  public static void main(String arg[]) 
  {
   try
  {
     ReadTextFile frame=new ReadTextFile();
     frame.setSize(300,200);
     frame.setVisible(true);
     textview tv=new textview();
     tv.Open();
     tv.Read();
     N=textview.name;
  }
   catch(Exception e)
   {}
 }
}
```

Comment: Yes. I want to print each word from a file into a text field. I'm using 2 programs for this and my fetch button is in another class program not in textview.java program.

Comment: After I delete my comment you replied...lol

Comment: Show your other class code too.

Comment: Have added the other class to my question itself.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this, it is working on my machine.....

```
public void Open()
{  
    try  
    {  
        scan =new Scanner(new File("C:/temp.txt")); 
        flag=true;
    }  
    catch(FileNotFoundException e)  
    {  
        flag=false;
        System.out.println("It wont working");  
    }
}  
public String Read()  
{   
    if(flag)
        name=scan.next();
    else
        return "End of the file";

    System.out.println(name); 
    if(!scan.hasNext())
    {
        scan.close();
        flag=false;
    }
    return name;
}  
@Override
public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) 
{
    if(e.getSource()==fetch)
    {  
        text1.setText(Read());  
    }
}
```

**Update1**

if you want to use another class for button then try following code:

create and object of `textview` class

```
textview tv = new textview();
```

call Open() method:

```
tv.Open();
```

and to get next text use:

```
text1.setText(tv.Read());
```

**Update2**

```
public class textview extends JFrame implements ActionListener
{  
Scanner scan;  
static String name;
JButton fetch;
JTextField text1;
testview2 t2 = new testview2();

public static void main(String args[])
{
new textview();
}
public textview()
{
setLayout(new FlowLayout());
setSize(200, 200);
fetch = new JButton("FetchData");
text1 = new JTextField(20);
add(fetch);
fetch.addActionListener(this);
add(text1);
setVisible(true);
t2.Open();
}
@Override
public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) 
{
if(e.getSource()==fetch)
    {  
       text1.setText(t2.Read());  
    } 
}
}

class testview2 {
Scanner scan;
static String name;
boolean flag=false;
public void Open()  
{  
    try  
    {  
        scan =new Scanner(new File("C:/temp.txt")); 
        flag=true;
    }  
    catch(FileNotFoundException e)  
    {  
        flag=false;
        System.out.println("It wont working");  
    }
}  
public String Read()  
{   
    if(flag)
        name=scan.next();
    else
        return "End of the file";

    System.out.println(name); 
    if(!scan.hasNext())
    {
        scan.close();
        flag=false;
    }
    return name;
}
}
```

Comment: Thanks. Im using 2 programs and my button is in another class program. So I think this cant be done.

Comment: @Neelam please see updated code, and let me know if it is still not working

Comment: I'm only getting the first word..:(

Comment: @Neelam try the updated `(UPDATE2)` code, its working as per your question

Comment: Thanks a lot for the help. Was badly struggling with this code. It working correctly.

Answer (score 0):

```
do{  
   name=scan.next();  

 } while(scan.hasNext());  
   System.out.println(name);
```

should be

```
do{  
   name=scan.next();  
   System.out.println(name); 
 }while(scan.hasNext());
```

Comment: Thank you. I ll make the changes but still i'm facing the same problem. I'm not able to fetch each word one after the other in the text field. Can i get some suggestions on it.

Answer (score 0):

you can implement this by storing all the word into the arraylist object and just move it as prev/next based on button click. As you are reading go ahead with small implementation

**Udated Method**

```
public List<String> Read(){
    //initialize 
    List<String> words = new ArrayList<String>();

    do{  
       name=scan.next();
       // now store all the words into the words object
       words.add(name);
    } while(scan.hasNext());
    return words;
}
```

this will read all the words from file and store into `words` object. Now on button click just move next by passing index with incremental value

```
int wordIndex = -1;

fetch.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {  
       public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent ae){  
           if(words.size>0 && wordIndex<words.size()){
               wordIndex++;
               String word = words.get(wordIndex);
               text1.setText(N);  
            }
       }  
  });
```

Comment: Thanks a lot. The button fetch is in a different file, so how will the value of words be passed on to it?? Sorry if my doubt is a silly one...

Comment: when you call the Read() then return that List object from this method so you get into any of the file

Comment: Can you please explain it. I actually dint understand.

Comment: :( Still finding errors. Have updated my question. Please check it.

Comment: Even though i merge the programs into one single class program and append the code you provided, its not working.